# Sum within a column given two or more conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

In MySQL, I am trying to sum values in a column given certain conditions. I have an example of some data below

```
Team    Season  Mth    Stat
A       1       1       4
A       1       1       4
A       1       2       7
A       1       2       9
B       1       1       6
B       1       1       6
B       1       2       6
B       1       2       9
C       1       1       1
C       1       1       3
C       1       2       3
C       1       2       6
```

But I need the output to show up as

```
Team    Season  Mth    Stat
A       1       1       8
A       1       2       16
B       1       1       12
B       1       2       15
C       1       1       4
C       1       2       9
```

So the `Stat` column is now the sum of the cells such that Match, Season, and Team are all the same. I have the code below. I see a lot of answers that use 'case' but that seems to be given logical operators that are not equal to each other. When I do it below, now it doesn't recognise the table where the columns are coming from. I do have a inner joins but the data itself is from one table. I get another error as well on the sum function because it requires one argument.

```
select
     Team
    ,Season
    ,Match
    --this is where I get lost-----------
    sum(
        select
          Stat
        From
          table
        Where
           Mth=Mth
          AND Season=Season
          AND Team=Team
         )
    --end of getting lost----------------
FROM
    table
Where
    Season IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
     Team
    ,Season
    ,Mth
Order BY
    Team ASC
```

Edit:
It turns out I need to use GROUP BY as the comments suggest. So I am not summing within a table, but I sum the variable given the Group By parameters.

Comment: Note that match is a reserved word in MySQL. Also, before going too much further, you're going to need to a PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Match is a short name for the actual column name. I will edit the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, it's simply:

```
SELECT Team
    ,Season
    ,Match
    ,Sum(Stat)
FROM table
GROUP BY
     Team
    ,Season
    ,Match
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple as this:

```
SELECT   Team,
         Season,
         Match,
         SUM(Stat)
FROM     Table
WHERE    Season IN (1,2)
GROUP BY Team,
         Season,
         Match
ORDER BY Team ASC
```

Please look at the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82e0b3/2) example.